# Angular 2 - web api : not get the posted data at api

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, angular2-forms, angular2-services

From the page i am sending data:

```
     register() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.Register = { firstName: 'aa', lastName: 'aa', email: 'aa', password: 'aa', cpassword: 'aa', gender: "male", dob: '2017-05-02' };
        this.userService.create(this.Register)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                alert("aa");
            },
            error => {
                // this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

I posted my data from Angular 2 service code is as below:

```
    create(UserRegister: UserRegister) {  
       return this.http.post('http://localhost:53625/api/UserLoginAPI/InsertUser', UserRegister, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    private jwt() {   
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'  });
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
```

for this i write code in the api is as below:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertUser(UserRegisterModel UserRegister)
        {
            int returnval = 0;
            returnval = objUserLoginBAL.InsertUser(objUserRegisterModel);
            return Json(returnval);
        }
```

i get the call at api side but my object not get any value. that is shown in image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
 create(UserRegister: UserRegister) {  
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:53625/api/UserLoginAPI/InsertUser', UserRegister, this.jwt(UserRegister)).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

private jwt(UserRegister: UserRegister) {   
let _body = JSON.stringify(UserRegister);
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });

return new RequestOptions({ 
          headers: headers,
          body: _body });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code snippet on how you are calling the create method with values?

Comment: Can you try adding body object in request options of headers and try ?

Comment: i can not understand please give me example

Comment: i get error like arguement of requestOptions is not assignable parameter  type of string | Request

Comment: Have updated my answer by taking your example, give a try.

Comment: i solve this by , in browser there was a CORS error. so make same port for my both projects and this issue was also solve with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your header construction. Try change this:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

to this:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Also introduce a field for **cpassword** in **UserRegisterModel**.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial page should look like this: Notice I removed the `cpassword` as it's not in your API Model

```
register() {
  this.loading = true;

  this.Register = { 
    dob: '2017-05-02' 
    email: 'aa', 
    firstName: 'aa', 
    gender: "male",
    lastName: 'aa', 
    password: 'aa',  
  };

  this.userService.create(this.Register)
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
        alert("aa");
    },(error:any) => {
        // this.alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
    });
}
```

Your Service: I cleaned up the `jwt()` function.

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs} from '@angular/http';

create(userRegister: UserRegister) {  
  let url:string = 'http://localhost:53625/api/UserLoginAPI/InsertUser';

  return this.http.post(url, userRegister, this.jwt())
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}

private jwt():RequestOptionsArgs {   
  let headers:Headers = new headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  let options:RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();

  options.headers = headers;

  return options;
}
```